# Not able to use a method declared in a class extending AbstractTableModel in JTable UI programming

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am getting the message `"method is never used locally"` after I've implemented the `removeRow` method. I am also unable to use/access this method.

```
class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Name"};

         ArrayList<Entry> list;

         public TableModel(Entry[] entries) {
              // assigns entries to list
         }

         public int getColumnCount() {
              return columnNames.length;
         }

         public String getColumnName(int col)
         {
             return columnNames[col];
         }

         public int getRowCount() {
              return list.size();
         }

             // this method gives a "never used locally" message
         public void removeRow(int row)
         {
             list.remove(row);
             fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
         }

         public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
              Entry entry = list.get(row);
              if(entry != null)
              {
                  switch (col) {
                  case 0:
                       return entry.getId();
                  case 1:
                       return entry.getName();
                  default:
                       return "";
                  }
              }
         }
     }
```

I then try to access the `removeRow(int row)` by the following way when the `delete` button is pressed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
          int i =1;
      table.getModel().removeRow(i); // removeRow not recognised
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast to your class. When you do `table.getModel` you obtain an  `AbstractTableModel`, which does not contain a method called `removeRow`

try

```
((TableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(i)
```

Comment: Dude I was stuck on this for ages.. Thank you! Everything works perfect - it was just a matter of getting the method recognised..

Comment: Note it is very confusing naming your class `TableModel` as this is also the name of the implemented interface (`javax.swing.table.TableModel`). You should rename it to something else to avoid confusion!

Answer (score 5):

```
class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
```

`TableModel` is an interface. Use a better name for your class. (I don't know what will happen when you try to make a class name the same as an interface name). Instead you should use something like:

```
class EntryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
```

Since your model is used to contain "Entry" objects.

```
table.getModel().removeRow(i);
```

The above code is confusing because the `getModel()` method returns a `TableModel`, but is this really the TableModel interface or the TableModel class?

To use your custom model your code should be something like:

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
EntryTableModel entryModel = (EntryTableModel)model;
entryModel.removeRow(i);
```

Comment: thanks, this is something for some reason slipped my attention.